# my ajax data is my pages html code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Well i do a simple ajax request to my controller and when i console log it just shows the html from my webpage.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modelLink').click(function(){
        var $reviewID = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/flyout',
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                'reviewID':$reviewID
            },
            success: function( data ){
                alert('Success Alert');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function flyout(){
        $result[] = ['value' =>'test', 'id' => '1'];
        return Response::json($result);
}
```

Route::

```
Route::post('flyout','DashboardController@flyout');
```

So i get the pop up "success alert". but my console shows

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="_token" content="UEUPcy9i7HMxTo65Ga2HumCplY158H8Ph5cD3eOP"/>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and this carries on and matches my pages html content.

Why is this?

Comment: shot in the dark: because the route `/flyout` is not mapped to the `flyout()` function you have defined there.

Comment: Why not? my route is Route::post('flyout','DashboardController@flyout');

Comment: Why are you passing a parameter to the Controller but not using it in the controller?

Comment: Should you not be using `echo` and not `return` to pass back data from the controller call

Comment: it was just a test i will be doing more in my controller